# The "entity_reference_revisions_entity_view" plugin does not exist

Tags: 8, paragraphs

This is related to Paragraphs module in Drupal 8.
I have enabled paragraphs module and Entity Reference Revisions module. Then I created a new paragraph type in Admin> Structure> Paragraph types. After that I added fields to the new paragraph type. After some configuration I tried to add the newly created paragraph type to a content type, in my case article. 
But I got the following error:

There was a problem creating field Paragraphs: The "entity_reference_revisions_entity_view" plugin does not exist.

This is a persistent error. As I have rebuild the site from the scratch, and I am getting the same error.
I will appreciated a help.

Comment: see issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2847643

Comment: @4k4 that is the same person, so that issue reference will not help much :)

Comment: Please enable verbose error logging and include screenshots of your field configuration and where/how the error shows up

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem when installing the module.

Check this with drush.

```
drush ev "var_dump(array_keys(\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.field.formatter')->getDefinitions()))"
```

Acc. to the error message the plugin is missing. Now reinstall the module:

```
drush pmu entity_reference_revisions
drush en entity_reference_revisions
```

and check again:

```
drush ev "var_dump(array_keys(\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.field.formatter')->getDefinitions()))"
```

If the plugin is not discovered report any errors you see.

Only debug this on a test site with no field data in this field type.